# Using cmponents inside ngIf in Angular 2.

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I want to use ngIf to show a component like this:

```
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li (click)="resetTab(1)" [ngClass]="{'active': first}" id="active"><a>Tab 1</a></li>
        <li (click)="resetTab(2)" [ngClass]="{'active': second}" ><a>Tab 2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div *ngIf="first" class="tab-pane fade in active">
         Content of tab 1
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="second" class="tab-pane fade">
          Content of tab 2:
          <events-list></events-list>
        </div>
      </div>
```

However for some reason I don't see my component appears when switching tabs (tabs itself switch just fine)

My component's code:

```
  resetTab(tab: number) {
    this.first = (tab == 1) ? true : false;
    this.second = (tab == 2) ? true: false;
  }
```

Comment: What tab component are you using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm using bootstrap to create tabs. And event-list is just my costome component which is displayed fine without 'ngif'.

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap or http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/ or plain bootstrap?

Comment: It's because you don't change class on your `tab-pane` divs. And your second tab remains always hidden https://plnkr.co/edit/Sg74uQ8Son78Cvkhg8Fb?p=info

Comment: @yurzui Thanks, I didn't notice it. By the way, why do you pass `$event` argument when calling on the second tab?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer just plain bootstrap, but thanks for attention, it's solved now

Comment: I forgot to remove it :) Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I try this for sidebar menu and working fine  you  can try this:
in html

```
<div class="sidebar-category">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li [class.active]="panelshow == 'tab1'">
            <a (click)="setPanel('tab1')">Tab1</a>
          </li>
          <li [class.active]="panelshow == 'tab2'">
            <a (click)="setPanel('tab2')">Tab2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div  *ngIf="panelshow == 'tab1'"> 
</div>
<div  *ngIf="panelshow == 'tab2'">
</div>
```

and in component:

```
  public panelshow:string;

   private setPanel(name) {
    this.panelshow = name;
 }
```